# Parameterizing the name of the store in backbone-localStorage.js

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

The standard way to use the [localStorage](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html) plugin for Backbone.js works like this:

```
  App.WordList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize : function(models, options){
    },

    localStorage : new Store('English')

  }
```

But I want to make different, parallel wordlist collections in different languages. So, I want to be able to instantiate the name of the Store upon initialization of the collection. AFAICT, this works ok:

```
  App.WordList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize : function(models, options){
      this.localStorage = new Store(options.language);
    }

  }
```

Then I can instantiate a WordList like:

```
  english = new Wordlist([], {language: 'English'});
```

Or:

```
  chinese = new Wordlist([], {language: 'Chinese'});
```

The thing is, I haven't really seen this done in any other examples and I'm wondering if anyone out there would have any "Eek! Don't do that, because..." sorts of reactions.

EDIT

I should add that I have already tried doing it this way:

```
App.WordList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  initialize : function(models, options){
  },

  localStorage : new Store(options.store)

}
```

And then:

```
  chinese = new Wordlist([], {language: 'Chinese'});
```

But for some reason `options.store` is coming up undefined.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, in your  `localStorage : new Store(options.store)` example, `options` is not local  to anything of the Collection you're making.  it would have to be defined in some outer context.  In that case, it's likely that `options` itself is undefined.

Comment: Isn't it local to `initialize()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to explain myself as an answer, so I'll go ahead and give one.

In:

```
App.WordList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize : function(models, options){
      ....   
  },
  localStorage : new Store(options.store)
})
```

This is really little different from

```
var newInstanceConfig = {
  initialize : function(models, options){
      ....   
  },
  localStorage : new Store(options.store)
}
App.WordList = Backbone.Collection.extend(newInstanceConfig);
```

Think of it this way; there's nothing magical about the object being passed in to `Backbone.Collection.extend(...)`. You're just passing in an ordinary object. The magic happens when `Backbone.Collection.extend` is invoked *with* that object as a parameter

Thus, the options parameter of the  object method `initialize` is completely different that which is being passed in to `new Store(...)`.  The function being assigned `initialize` is defining the scope of options.  Who knows where the one referred to in `new Store(options.store)` is defined.  It could be `window.options` or it could be options defined in some other scope.  If it's undefined, you're likely getting an error

That being said, I only see two or three strategic options (oh jeez, forgive the pun please!).

Whenever you're creating a new instance of the collection, either:

1. Pass in the language and let your Backbone collection create the `new Store(..)` where needed.
2. Pre-Create the Stores and either pass or give the specific Store want to that instance (either directly through its constructor or maybe you have your constructor "look-up" the appropriate pre-created Store).
3. And finally, I guess you could delegate the task of creating stores to another object and have it implement either options one or two. (Basically a Store Factory/Resource Manager kinda thing).

*What you need to figure out* is which one of those strategies should work for you.  I have never used localStorage so, unfortunately, I can't help you in that regard.  What I can do is ask, is there ever going to be multiple instances created from App.Wordlist where there might accidentally be created two of the same kind of Store?

<strike>In fact, I've got another question.  where is this `Store` defined?  Are you sure that's not defined somewhere in one of your other API libraries you're using?  Perusing the localStorage docs I know about mentions something of a  `Storage` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) but nothing of a `Store`.  So you might want to figure out that as well.</strike>

Edit #1:  Nevermind, [I see you mentioned where `Store` was defined.](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html)

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by creating a method which allows you to configure the localStorage after instantiation:

```
var PageAssetCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend ({

initialize: <stuff>

model: <something>
...

setLocalStorage: function ( storageKey ) {
    this.localStorage = new Backbone.LocalStorage(storageKey),      
},
});
```

you can then set the localStorage after you have set up the collection:

```
fooPageAssets = new PageAssetCollection();
fooPageAssets.setLocalStorage('bar');
```